# How would files be uploaded to a 2nd domain?

Tags: files, .htaccess

So I have a Drupal site on my company intranet, and when uploading files, it all goes to the default/files folder as normal, however when uploading video files specifically, the base url is different from the Drupal base, it's a second domain specifically created for hosting assets.

I.E.

Drupal base / source of all uploads except videos

```
server.domain.com
```

Source of videos

```
assetserver.domain.com/sites/default/files/movie.mp4
```

I have no access to the server outside of the Drupal back end, and I cannot find the settings for specifying a domain anywhere (within File settings, Media settings, etc). As far as I know, there is no mention of this 2nd domain (`assetserver`) anywhere within the drupal codebase or backend. I'm just wondering if there's a setting outside of Drupal that can be used to set this, for example in the .htaccess file or something along those lines?

Any insight from someone who has worked with similar issues will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Remote stream wrapper](https://drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper) may help...also look [Media Mover](https://drupal.org/project/media_mover) module...and, at the end, take a look on [THIS](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49580/upload-media-to-different-sub-domain) post...